# Is there a way to split results into different columns

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumproduct

[File Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwKCP.jpg)

I have a file with sales information.  Next to each row I have the month and year of the sale.  Its an ODBC report and gets updated based on parameters. 
I would like all the data with Month 1 and Year 2018 to show up in a column labeled January, and then all the rows with Month 2 and Year 2018 in a column labelled February (it will actually be two columns, one for amount and one for qty).  See sample attached of what I'd like it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do this with IF() and AND():
And just noticed I miss-labelled columns F and G...

[image]

But as something to get you going...

You could do a lookup to convert January to 1 etc, when you drag across you have to make sure the columns C and D ($ and Qty are still referenced...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add into K3 and L3 these:

K3 `=if($G3=month(datevalue("1. " & K$1)),$E3,"")`

L3 `=if($G3=month(datevalue("1. " & K$1)),$F3,"")`

Then you can copy paste this to the rest of your table.
Explanation:
`month(month(datevalue("1. " & K$1))` turns January into 1, February into 2, ...
so you can just compare that to the month column.
The `$` keep the parts fixed when you copy paste - other cell references are changed.
e.g if you copy K3 to K4 the formular will read as

`=if($G4=month(datevalue("1. " & K$1)),$E4,"")`

while if you copy it to M3

`=if($G3=month(datevalue("1. " & M$1)),$E3,"")`

But possibly what you actually want is to use a pivot table. That could give you all the monthly values for each person in one row.